# how to read a file froma USB token via Java code

Tags: java

I am looking to digitally sign a pdf in Java code. The digital signature is USB token based.

How does one read a file from a USB token in Java?

Comment: You have to search and try it. This is not a right place to ask code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely broad and of limited detail, so an authoritative answer is impossible. However, as a best effort answer before the question gets closed, there are two routes to go.

First, if this is a special purpose USB device, then read the documentation from the manufacturer.

Second, if this is a generic USB token, and you're just trying to open a file with an encryption key, then lookup the KeyStore class.